# defaultdict of pd.Series

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, series, defaultdict

The result of the following code doesn't meet my expectation.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict

t_dict = {'a_b': pd.Series(np.arange(3))}
t_def_dict = defaultdict(pd.Series)
for k, v in t_dict.items():
    x, y = k.split('_')
    t_def_dict[y] += v
```

I got an empty series, while my expectation is pd.Series(0, 1, 2)

```
> t_def_dict     # expect pd.Series(0, 1, 2)
  defaultdict(pandas.core.series.Series, {'b': Series([], dtype: float64)})
```

My question is why this is the case and how to modify it to meet the expectation?

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused the plus operator for lists (which does concatenation) with plus operator for Series which does element-wise addition:

```
print(pd.Series(np.arange(3)) + pd.Series(np.arange(5)))

0    0.0
1    2.0
2    4.0
3    NaN
4    NaN
```

As you can see from the example above, if you start with empty Series, you are going to get an empty one because the size of the left operand is the size of the result.

To achieve what you want you may want to go with [`Series.append`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.append.html):

```
t_def_dict[y] = t_def_dict[y].append(v)
```

Resulting in:

```
defaultdict(<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>, {'b': 0    0
1    1
2    2
dtype: int64})
```